# What is wrong? Update time_last_login and date_last_login PDO MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hey all so when i login my ip will change but the time and date won't update..
if someone could tell me what is wrong it will help alot haha..

here is my code:

```
public function setIp()
{
    $ip_adress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    $temp_user = $_SESSION['temp_user'];
    $sql2 = 'UPDATE `gebruikers` SET
                    `time_last_login` = :time_last_login,
                    `date_last_login` = :date_last_login,
                    `last_login` = :ip_adress
                    WHERE  `id` = :id';
    $sth2 = $this->db->prepare($sql2);
    $sth2->bindParam(':ip_adress',$ip_adress);
    $sth2->bindParam(':id',$temp_user->geefId());
    $sth2->bindParam(':date_last_login', date("Y-m-d"));
    $sth2->bindParam(':time_last_login', time("H:i:s"));
    $sth2->execute();


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sth2->bindParam(':time_last_login', time("H:i:s"));
```

is wrong and should be

```
$sth2->bindParam(':time_last_login', date("H:i:s"));
```

Change "bindParam" to "bindValue" too and see if that helps, it might not like you passing a generated string via bindParam. Otherwise, this query runs fine for me locally in a similar setting.

```
public function setIp()
{
    $ip_adress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $temp_user = $_SESSION['temp_user'];

    $sql2 = "UPDATE `gebruikers` SET "
          . "time_last_login` = :time_last_login, "
          . "date_last_login` = :date_last_login, "
          . "last_login` = :ip_adress "
          . "WHERE  `id` = :id";
    $sth2 = $this->db->prepare($sql2);
    $sth2->bindValue(':ip_adress',$ip_adress);
    $sth2->bindValue(':id',$temp_user);
    $sth2->bindValue(':date_last_login', date("Y-m-d"));
    $sth2->bindValue(':time_last_login', date("H:i:s"));
    $sth2->execute();


}
```

Comment: Ima check now hold on :)

Comment: it's not working.. my database colums are time and date format that's just good right?

Comment: Solved it forgot one small thing :)